# How to build query from SQL by Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Tags: sql, orm, doctrine, query-builder

I'm new in Doctrine ORM, and I need help with building QueryBuilder command. I have a SQL command and I need covert to QueryBuilder.

`$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();`

The SQL is:

```
SELECT `user`.*
FROM `user`
JOIN `friends` ON `user`.`id` != $uid AND  (`user`.`id` = `friends`.`origin` OR  `user`.`id` = `friends`.`destination`)
WHERE `friends`.`origin` = $uid OR `friends`.`destination` = $uid;
```

`user` is `App\Model\Database\Entity\User`
and `friends` is `App\Model\Database\Entity\Friends`

The `$uid` is a user whose friends I want to see. As result of query I need array of `User` entites.

`Friends` is simple table with unique ID and with `origin` and `destination`, which are `User` IDs, when I want to ask someone for friendship, `origin` will be my UID and `destination` will be his UID. This function above is for getting users friends, no matter who called for friendship.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could convert your SQL to DQL and it will look similar to

```
SELECT u
FROM App\Model\Database\Entity\User  u
JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Friends f WITH u.id != :uid 
    AND  (u.id = f.origin OR  u.id = f.destination)
WHERE f.origin = :uid OR f.destination = :uid
```

and in query builder you can write it as

```
$em->createQuery('
        SELECT u
        FROM App\Model\Database\Entity\User  u
        JOIN App\Model\Database\Entity\Friends f WITH u.id != :uid 
            AND  (u.id = f.origin OR  u.id = f.destination)
        WHERE f.origin = :uid OR f.destination = :uid'
        )->setParameters(array(
            'uid' => $uid
        ));
```

Comment: Ah, it didn't occur to me. Can you please tell me why do you use 'WITH' instead of 'ON'?

Comment: So I read the documentation and I get it. Thank you for the advice.